# Sudo - is there a command to check if I have sudo and/or how much time is left?

Tags: bash, sudo

See title.  I want a command that lets me query `sudo`.  Ideally it would return success if I still have `sudo` and false if `sudo` has expired.  Getting the time left might also be useful (although if I was concerned I could just do `sudo -v` to revalidate.)  Oh and it shouldn't have to ask for a password.

The closest thing I've found is `sudo -n true`, but the `-n` option is only present on my Centos 5 machine at work.  `-n` fails if it has to ask for a password.  Is there any other way to get this functionality?  Assume I don't actually have root on all the machines I work with, so I can't install new versions of sudo to my liking.

For what it's worth I'm doing this so I can get my prompt to indicate sudo status.  I like knowing which terminals are actively sudo-able.  I also have a prompt that changes colors when I'm root, but I don't use root very often so that's of limited use.

Comment: Seems suited for superuser.com

Comment: Daenyth, seems reasonable.  Reposted!  http://superuser.com/questions/195781/sudo-is-there-a-command-to-check-if-i-have-sudo-and-or-how-much-time-is-left

Comment: What systems are you using that don't have `-n`?

Comment: Please don't repost to Super User or Server Fault (and later to certain, yet to be announced stack exchange sites) because migration of the original will cause un-intended duplicates. I'll flag this for moderation, but in the future just wait.

Comment: Closed as off-topic to avoid creating a dupe by migrating.  Thanks for the flag @dmckee.